# Get values from url using useParams

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have a React form with Material-UI. I would like to get the id from the URL link using `useParams` and make some API requests in order to populate form-data:

```
http://localhost:3001/profile?ids=9459377
```

Main app.tsx:

```
function App() {
  return (
      <Router>
        <Navbar />
        <Switch>
          <Route path='/ticket-profile/:ids' component={TicketProfile} />
        </Switch>
      </Router>
  );
}
```

I use this code to open a new page and pass `ids` param:

```
history.push(`/ticket-profile/ids=${id}`)
```

I need to get the data into this page:

```
export default function TicketProfile(props: any) {
    let { ids } = useParams();
    
    const [ticket, setTicket] = useState<TicketDTO[]>([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        getSingleTicket();    
    }, []);

    const getSingleTicket = async () => {
        getTicket(ids)
            .then((resp) => {
                setTicket(resp.data);
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.error(error);
            });
    }
```

But for this line `let { ids }` I get:

`TS2339: Property 'ids' does not exist on type '{}'.`

Do you know how I can fix this issue?

Comment: I guess you are using useParams from react-router?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So this is the url

```
http://localhost:3001/profile?ids=9459377
```

In your code

```
const MyComponent = () => {

 const params = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
```

That's it! Now we should move on to getting the value and checking the existence of the query strings

Check if it has the query;

```
params.has('ids')
```

or get the value that is inside the query string

```
params.get('ids')
```

You can also show them conditionally

```
console.log(params.has('ids')?params.get('ids'):"")
```

#### Update:

Check out the working example

[https://codesandbox.io/s/peaceful-https-vz9y3?file=/src/App.js\](https://codesandbox.io/s/peaceful-https-vz9y3?file=/src/App.js%5C)
This is how we should use it in your case

```
export default function TicketProfile(props: any) {
    const params = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
    const ids = params.get('ids');
    const [ticket, setTicket] = useState<TicketDTO[]>([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        getSingleTicket();    
    }, []);

    const getSingleTicket = async () => {
        getTicket(ids)
            .then((resp) => {
                setTicket(resp.data);
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.error(error);
            });
    }
```

Comment: Can you show me how I can implement this with `useParams`, please?

Comment: I think with this approach you don't need to use `useParams`.

Comment: See updates in the answer.

Comment: Also have a look at this https://codesandbox.io/s/peaceful-https-vz9y3?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Try to add query strings to url in sandbox's simulator.

Comment: This answer has value, but it's not what the OP asks for.  I suggest you edit your answer to mention that.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are using useParams from react-router. If so then try so here

```
 let { ids } = useParams<{ ids: Array<any>}>();
```

Comment: It would be better if the type weren't `any`, but instead included the expected fields.

Comment: Yep it can be better as you suggested. My quick solution is just to fix the typescripts issue

Answer (score -1):

You are pushing a wrong path to the history. Try it like this:

```
history.push(`/ticket-profile/${id}`)
```

Comment: It's not working again.